# How to route a netlify requests on the edge for cached resources with different privilege-requirements?

Tags: next.js, netlify

I have a NextJS application that runs on Netlify and pulls data from a headless CMS. In the CMS, you can tag articles to be either:

- for free
- you must log in
- you must have a paid subscription

If your account-level doesn't match the requirements you shall be met by a paywall. Therefore, each post has one or two different cached versions:

- One of its free (the content version)
- two for the other types (one version with paywall and one with content).

My structure in NextJS would look like this:

```
- pages
 | ...
 | - articles
    | - [slug]
       | - index.ts   <- Renders paywall or content if not no paywall required
       | - content.ts <- only exists if content is not free, otherwise 404
 | ...
```

My approach is to set a JWT on login with an information if the user has a paid subscription or not inside the token. This way I know all three states:

- No cookie -> Not logged in
- With Cookie -> Decode cookie on the edge and check the respective key in the JWT

However, I have no idea how to determine if the user's level is enough to see the post without calling the application. How do I know the post's requirement? I could rewrite the request behind the scenes to `/content` if a cookie is present, but then again I do not know if it only requires login or paid subscription to go through. Also I would have to handle 404 cases if the `content.ts` does not exist if its free. I am sure there must be a better design?

The file-structure can also be changed if you have better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar with best practices in Netifly, I can offer a 2 step solution that may work depending on your specific implementation. Keep your file structure, as it is suitable for your needs.

I am assuming you have the JWT stored in cookies?

1. [Lambda functions](https://blog.openreplay.com/serverless-functions-in-next-js/)
   If you are familiar with serverless functions in Next.js, you can set one up as a "pseudo-route" to validate and decode incoming JWT from your cookies. This checks user access without interacting with the application.
2. [`_redirects`](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-redirects-file)
   Netifly has built-in redirect support in the file directory system. Just redirect protected requests to the lambda function when needed.

This allows you to return your 404 or content when needed.